# IBM MobileFirst installation on AWS Linux

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am planning to install IBM MobileFirst on AWS Linux (RedHat) instance and move our existing app to it.

I have installed IBM MobileFirst via Eclipse and developed app on windows environment and have no idea on Linux.

I need some guidelines to achieve this.

Comment: Please take a moment and actually explain your question. Do you want to move your development to Linux? Do you want to move your app to a production environment on AWS? **explain**.

Comment: Sorry ,we need to  install IBM MobileFirst on a new AWS Linux (RedHat) instance and move our existing app on to it. Hope am clear!!

Comment: You did not answer my question. Read it again. Are you intending to DEVELOP on that Linux? Does it have a UI? Is this for DEVELOPMENT or PRODUCTION?

Comment: Sorry again , we are intended only to install IBM MobileFirst server on Linux instance, and upload the existing apps..

Answer (score 0):

There are no available up-to-date instructions for deploying MobileFirst Server to Amazon EC2, other than the following which are for Worklight 5: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_install_worklight_server_on_amazon_ec21?lang=en

The general idea is the same, though.